# Force resize a window

Tags: windows, .net-framework, dpi, scaling

I have an high resolution monitor, so i am forced to increase the DPI settings, because i don't like to lose my vision to read smallish text.
Windows 7 does a great job on scaling, and it works great

The program arises when i installed a very expensive and poorly coded accounting software: (for example, they use ms sql express server for just an user.... do they know about sqlite? and then it's just a quickly coded crystal reports frontend... totally disappointed seeing the price that i paid - over 3000 euro)

Ok, the window size is fixed to 600x400, has the resize borders, but has a senseless "OnDraw" function that resizes the window again... how i can disable it?
The program is coded in vb.net (i know because of the frequent crashes that refers to an unhandled sql exception when importing data... disappointed again)

How easy it is to remove that function with .net reflector?

There is a software that forces a window to be another size?

I phoned the tech support, their fix is to decrease the dpi setting and lose my vision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed the program with [AltMove](http://www.deskex.com/Altmove/index.asp)

Just right-click on the window and move it up to force-maximize it :-D

Answer (score 2):

You would want to run your program in a Windowed mode (often used for running games too)

But you might want to check into the Compatibility settings of your application and check the "Disable display scaling on high DPI settings"

[image]

Comment: oh, i did not see that compatibility option. thanks for the reminder!

Comment: oh no, it does not work, as that program it's an hacked bunch of programs: the main program it's just a launcher, and every form it's a standalone program.... this coders should be banned to use a keyboard for the rest of their lifes, considering that the price of this software is more than 3000 euro/year...

Comment: I fear your only real solution would be something like XP Mode or a virtual machine, in which you use a normal DPI